# Multiple average value on querying

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm querying the average value of the daily availability for the report on the back end of our monitoring tool, the problem is when I query the I got multiple average value. Below the example output and the query:

```
NodeName| DailyNodeAvailability 
Manila  |    81%     
Subic   |    91%
        |    85%
        |    28%
Laguna  |    85%


SELECT Convert(DateTime,Floor(Cast((DateTime) as Float)),0) AS SummaryDate,
Nodes.Caption AS NodeName,
AVG(DailyNodeAvailability.Availability) AS AVERAGE_of_Availability 

FROM 
Nodes INNER JOIN DailyNodeAvailability ON (Nodes.NodeID = DailyNodeAvailability.NodeID)


WHERE 
( DateTime BETWEEN 43094 AND 43125 )

GROUP BY Convert(DateTime,Floor(Cast((DateTime) as Float)),0), 
Nodes.Caption


ORDER BY SummaryDate ASC
```

Comment: Edit your question and provide the query that you are using.  Also, sample data would help others understand what is going on.

Comment: Here the query, thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems that grouping on "!Convert(DateTime,Floor(Cast((DateTime) as Float)),0),"
could provide more than 1 value for Node name.

Try to group only on 
GROUP BY Nodes.Caption